# what is the difference between think time and time out in monkey talk

Tags: android, automated-tests, monkeytalk

in monkey talk while i am wring the test cases there is two time available, one is think time and other is time out. Think time is the time during which the program waits and other is time out i am confused about these two related to monkey talk working. Can anyone help to make me understand please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation
`Timeout – Maximum time to retry the command before failing`
In General words  For example if for a button tap we give Timeout as 5000ms(5sec)
Monkey talk will execute Tap for 5sec Afterwards it will show error if it is not success.

`ThinkTime-– How long to pause before executing the command`
For example, on button click if we are loading a list from server, if we give ThinkTime as some 10000ms(10sec), monkeytalk holds(waits) the next command execution for the next 10sec until the list is populated. where we might be having command execution based on the list being populated. 
U can refer this very good pdf [here](http://www.stickyminds.com/sites/default/files/presentation/file/2014/T16.pdf)